# Regular expression- add target="blank" to all <a> tag links in my content

Tags: c#, regex

Can some one help me create a regular expression in C#.net to add `target="_blank"` to all `<a>` tag links in my content?

If the link already has a target set then replace it with `"_blank"`. The purpose is to open all links in my content in a new window.

Appreciate your help

-dotnet rocks

Comment: dotnetrocks, but html parsing with regex don't http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Looking at the [specification for XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-starttags), this task might be possible for valid XHTML input. But it will look ugly.

Comment: A simple regex would probably match inside comments and CDATA areas, which might or might not be a problem for you. These complications are the reason why here on Stack Overflow one usually gets a certain link as an answer for "parse HTML with regex" questions.

Answer (score 10):

There are a lot of mentions regarding [*not to use regex when parsing HTML*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), so you could use [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) for this:

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(yourHtml);

var links = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
foreach (HtmlNode link in links)
{
    if (link.Attributes["target"] != null)
    {
        link.Attributes["target"].Value = "_blank";
    }
    else
    {
        link.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank");
    }
}
```

this will add(or replace if necessary) `target='_blank'` to all the anchors in your document.

Comment: Then use var newHtml = document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;

Answer (score 7):

```
RegEx.Replace(inputString, "<(a)([^>]+)>", "<$1 target=""_blank""$2>")
```

It will add target also in those anchor tags which already have target present

Comment: Nice solution.
I just changed the regex to following: 
RegEx.Replace(input, "<(a)([^>]+)>", "<$1 target=\"_blank\"$2>");
The only change is that I use escape before the double quotes insisde the regex replace, otherwise I get compile error.

Comment: Wouldn't this screw up all other tags starting with a? , i.e. <area>. And why bother looking for the closing of the tag if you will add the target attribute anyway?
Wouldn't RegEx.Replace(inputString, "<a ", "<a target=""_blank"" ") suffice?

Comment: I came up two regexps in sequence to achieve this. Note - I'm using JS. Remove target if it exists `result = result.replace(/(<a [^>]*)(target="[^"]*")([^>]*>)/gi, '$1$3');`, add new target="_blank" `result = result.replace(/(<a [^>]*)(>)/gi, '$1 target="_blank"$2');`

Answer (score 2):

I did this with an extension method similar to the approach Alex showed. The method:

```
// Return the input string with all parsed HTML links having the "target" attribute set to specified value
// Links without a target attribute will have the attribute added, existing attributes values are updated
public static string SetHtmlLinkTargetAttribute(this string inputHtmlString, string target)
{
    var htmlContent = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlContent.LoadHtml(inputHtmlString);

    // Parse HTML content for links
    var links = htmlContent.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
    foreach (var link in links)
    {
        link.SetAttributeValue("target", target);
    }

    return htmlContent.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
}
```

And using it to clean up my links:

```
// Enforce targets for links as "_blank" to open in new window
asset.Description = asset.Description.SetHtmlLinkTargetAttribute("_blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RegEx.Replace(inputString, "<(a)([^>]+)>", "<$1 target=""_blank""$2>")
```

Comment: Good quick answer, but you don't account for target="_blank" or target="something else" already being in the regex. Something to think about.